# MongoDB - Mongoose find command to get only values from an embedded object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Schema looks something like this.

```
{
  _id: '1',
  items: {
    'id1': 'item1',
    'id2': 'item2',
    'id3': 'item3'
  }
}
```

Following is the query

```
ItemModel.find({}, {
  items: 1,
  _id: 0
});
```

And the result of the find query is:

```
{ "items" : { "21" : "item21", "22" : "item22", "23" : "item23" } }
{ "items" : { "31" : "item31", "32" : "item32", "33" : "item33" } }
{ "items" : { "11" : "item11", "12" : "item32", "13" : "item13" } }
```

What I want is:

```
["item21", "item22", "item23",
 "item31", "item32", "item33",
 "item11", "item12", "item13"]
```

Currently, I am doing the processing on the node.js end for getting the above. I want to reduce the output payload size coming from MongoDB. The "items" key is redundant and the IDs mentioned are not required as well when I fetch it. Here, the IDs are quite small like 21, 22, 13, etc. but those are acutally 50 characters in length.

If not the above, any other efficient alternatives are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One example of how to achieve that is the following aggregation:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $objectToArray: '$items',
      },
    },
  },
  { $unwind: '$items' },
  {
    $project: {
      items: '$items.v',
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: {
        $push: '$items',
      },
    },
  }
];
```

What this does is first we convert with `$project` & `$objectToArray` field to an array so that we could use `$unwind`. This way we'll have documents with different `item`s. Now we convert with another `$project` to make it a string instead of an object (which would be `{ v: <value>, k: <value> }`. And, finally, we `$group` them together.

Final result:

[image]

To get exactly that list, you'll need in your code to access `items` field, like `result[0].items` (`[0]` because aggregation will return an array).

Comment: This is perfect. I went through the docs are was able to achieve it as id: item... But now you have taken it one step further by sending id as null and rest of the items in an array. Thank you so much! This makes it one document.

Comment: This should work for smaller datasets. If the document size is greater than 16 MB, this will fail. (Like it did for me).

Comment: Document sizes were not taken into consideration in this case. But if your document is large, you can also use `$project` stage as the first stage to project only needed fields (probably `items` is the only one needed for you). Without seeing what kind of  document you have (because of size limit), it's a bit hard to determine where the improvement could be made :)

Comment: No @Gytis TG. The final output document i.e. {_id: null, items: []} is exceeding the limit of 16MB because it has 0.3 million items in the array. The total size of the output it 52MB for me. That is why, I am fetching it as [{_id: 'item11'},{_id: 'item21'},{...}, ...]. So, each document is just a few bytes. But the final size of Output is still ~52MB. And thanks a lot for your answer. It is very insightful. Might come in handy some other time.